# NoMethodError: undefined method `match?' for "Ruby":String

Tags: ruby, regex, match, nomethoderror, code-documentation

I'm trying to check whether input from user matches RegEx `[a-zA-z]` so I've checked the docs for proper method. I found `match?` in [Ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) and copied the example shown in docs to irb, but instead of `true` I'm getting this:

```
2.3.3 :001 > "Ruby".match?(/R.../) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `match?' for "Ruby":String
Did you mean?  match
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Why this method doesn't work in my irb?

Comment: I notice you are using 2.3.3 and the doc is for 2.4.0. That may be relevant.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`String#match?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) and [`Regexp#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F) are **Ruby 2.4** new methods. Check [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/) and [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/55061).

This new syntax is **not only an alias**. It's faster than other methods mainly because it doesn't update the `$~` global object. According to [this](https://blog.blockscore.com/new-features-in-ruby-2-4/) benchmark, it runs up to **three times faster** than other methods.

BTW, in order to achieve your goal (check whether a string matches a regex), you might **[1]** update your ruby version to use this new feature or **[2]** use another approach.

For instance, you can use the [=~ operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E), that returns *nil* if not found, or the *position* where the matchs starts. Can be used like that:

```
if "Ruby" =~ /R.../
   puts "found"
end
```

Comment: There was a syntax error. I took the liberty to edit it.

Comment: @EricDuminil Sure, I didn't notice. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading my Ruby version from 2.3.3 to 2.4.0 solved this problem for me.